# Why does dplyr convert POSIXct objects

Tags: r, dplyr, posixct

I have a date-time object of class POSIXct.  I need to adjust the values by adding several hours.  I understand that I can do this using basic addition.  For example, I can add 5 hours to a POSIXct object like so:

```
x <- as.POSIXct("2009-08-02 18:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
x
[1] "2009-08-02 18:00:00 PDT"
x + (5*60*60)
[1] "2009-08-02 23:00:00 PDT"
```

Now I have a data frame in which some times are ok and some are bad.

```
> df
         set_time      duration           up_time
1 2009-05-31 14:10:00        3 2009-05-31 11:10:00
2 2009-08-02 18:00:00        4 2009-08-02 23:00:00
3 2009-08-03 01:20:00        5 2009-08-03 06:20:00
4 2009-08-03 06:30:00        2 2009-08-03 11:30:00
```

Note that the first data frame entry has an 'up_time' less than the 'set_time'.  So in this context a 'good' time is one where the set_time < up_time.  And a 'bad' time is one in which set_time > up_time. I want to leave the good entries alone and fix the bad entries.  The bad entries should be fixed by creating an 'up_time' that is equal to the 'set_time' + duration.  I do this with the following dplyr pipe:

```
 df1 <- tbl_df(df) %>% mutate(up_time = ifelse(set_time > up_time, set_time + 
 (duration*60*60), up_time))

df1
# A tibble: 4 x 3
set_time            duration     up_time
<dttm>                 <dbl>       <dbl>
1 2009-05-31 14:10:00       3. 1243815000.
2 2009-08-02 18:00:00       4. 1249279200.
3 2009-08-03 01:20:00       5. 1249305600.
4 2009-08-03 06:30:00       2. 1249324200.
```

Up time has been coerced to numeric:

```
> str(df1)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       4 obs. of  3 variables:
$ set_time: POSIXct, format: "2009-05-31 14:10:00" "2009-08-02 18:00:00" 
"2009-08-03 01:20:00" "2009-08-03 06:30:00"
$ duration: num  3 4 5 2
$ up_time : num  1.24e+09 1.25e+09 1.25e+09 1.25e+09
```

I can convert it back to the desired POSIXct format using:

```
> as.POSIXct(df1$up_time,origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2009-05-31 17:10:00 PDT" "2009-08-02 23:00:00 PDT" "2009-08-03 06:20:00 
PDT" "2009-08-03 11:30:00 PDT"
```

But I feel like this last step shouldn't be necessary.  Can I/How can I avoid having dplyr change my variable formatting?

Comment: It's not **dplyr** it is `ifelse`. You might prefer to use `if_else` from **dplyr**. I think it will preserve the datetime class, but I'm actually not 100% sure.

Comment: Yeah, `if_else` will be more strict and actually throw an error, prompting you to make sure that `up_time` is also a datetime, not a double. `ifelse` collapses everything to double (numeric).

Comment: @joran if_else solved the problem.  thanks.  how do I mark your comment as the accepted answer?

Comment: Write it up as an answer yourself...it should let you mark it as accepted after a short delay (I think it makes you wait a few hours).